# Objects having their own Linked List

Tags: c++, object, linked-list

I'm in the process of learning C++. I've come across a rather interesting issue where I wish to store within a Customer class their food tray. The basic idea would be that one customer can have a tray which consists of drinks and foods.

My original thought was to use following class.

```
class Customer
{
private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    int tablenumber;
    //LinkList<Tray> myTray = new LinkList<Tray>();
    //or
    //LinkList<Tray> myTray;
public:
    Customer();
    Customer(std::string sFirstName, std::string sLastName, 
        int sTableNumber);
    ~Customer(void);
```

What would be the correct way for dealing with having an object store a Linklist within itself? So upon calling the customer constructor, they can have orders added to it?

Comment: Same way you do with the other members you already have.

Comment: You have a customer with a list of Trays. Do you really want your customer to hold many trays? Or should they hold one single tray which can contain many items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me address a more fundamental issue before going to the details.

It is **not** good to think about `LinkList<Tray> myTray = new LinkList<Tray>();` as a solution.

Think about it this way,  **Every** Customer will have **their own** Tray. So you need a new tray for each customer.

Remember that a class is just a blueprint.

So go with `LinkList<Tray> myTray;` and then in constructor of your object, allot a new tray each time a customer is created. 
it would look like :

```
Customer()
{
//other construction 
 myTray = new LinkList<Tray>();
}
```

Note that you must now declare it like `LinkList<Tray> * myTray;` if you want to allocate the list dynamically.

now you can use `myTray` as per your requirements. Eg. you may like to call  `myTray.addToList(MyNewItem)` and the likes.

**Assumption**:

When every object shares the same value, you declare them as `static`. But you mentioned `within a Customer class` **their** `food tray` so i am assuming this is not the case here.

Comment: OP hasn't said anything about `static`.

Comment: @axiom Could you give me a little example of allotting that tray within a constructor?

Comment: I get an intellisense error on myTray "IntelliSense member "Customer::myTray" is not a type name".

Comment: Why would you allocate the linked list dynamically? ``myTray`` is not a pointer, so this solution wouldn't compile. But there is no reason for the dynamic allocation anyway.

Comment: Updated the answer. It got slipped somehow, i think the answer should be more focussed on the fact that class should be visualized as a layout. I don't think i lose anything by dynamic allocation. Please correct me if i am mistaken.

Comment: @juanchopanza Its because the example I've given is a smaller version of what I'm working on. In which a customer doesn't just have a Tray with meals but they could request services (Birthdays, balloons). I guess i should have stated that from the start, Sorry.

Comment: Well, with dynamic allocation, you would have to explain that ``myTable`` has to be a pointer, and that it is up to the ``Customer`` class to manage its lifetime, which means deleting it in the destructor. It also means that you have to explain that OP must write an assignment operator, a copy constructor, and, if they have C++11 support, a move assignment operator and a move copy constructor. Or you can just drop the dynamic allocation because it really isn't worth it.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think you miss interprit what i'm trying to do, I have no need for a myTable. As it would be visual inspection of the table number given to a customer. So when a customer object is deleted from the system all of their orders go along aswell.

Comment: @Melky sorry, I meant ``myTray`` in the last comment, and it was intended as a comment on part of this answer. I was trying to highlight all the added complexity that comes from using a dynamically allocated linked list.

Comment: In simpler terms , i risk a memory leak if the programmer forgets to take necessary care. point taken.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your customer to have the ability to hold many food items in a food tray. So it would make sense to hold some kind of container of food items (not necessarily a linked list) and give the `Customer` type methods to add or remove food items. This container would represent the tray you're talking about:

```
class Customer
{
private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    LinkList<FoodItem> myTray;
public:
    AddFoodItemToTray(const FoodItem& item) { myTray.push(item);}
    RemoveFoodItemFromTray(const FoodItem& item) { myTray.remove(item=; } 
};
```

If you want your `Customer` class to be initializable from a list of elements, then you can just add a constructor for that:

```
explicit Customer(const LinkList<FoodItem>& tray) : myTray(tray) {}
```

It is probably best to leave the table number out of the customer, and let some kind of table class know which curtomers it holds.

Answer (score 0):

write another constructor which takes linkedlist of tray type object as parameter.

Comment: May be you can explain it bit more.